# Remove multiple tables with the same class name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove multiple tables with the same class name in a row using jQuery.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here because I can not get it to work.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattipoo/BgdnF/1/)

---

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".closeprod").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    elem = $(this).parent().parent();
    //get sn            
    prodsn = $(".tbl").find(".prodsn:eq(0)");
    sn = $(prodsn[0]).html().substr(5);
    url = "delprod.asp?email=email@example.com&sn=" + sn + "&t=" + tpl;
    //remove product from xml file
    $.get(url, function (data, status) {
        if (data == "OK") {
            //remove product from template                  
            elem.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest()` to get to the parent table instead of `parent().parent()` as changing html will break your jquery code:

```
elem = $(this).closest("table").closes("td");
```

code:

```
$(".closeprod").live("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            elem = $(this).closest("table").closest("td");
                    //remove product from template                  
                    elem.remove();
        });
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ExnkV/)

Comment: @mmz your code has other issues as well it contains variable used which are not even defined

Comment: @mmz i have excluded your ajax call code to make this thing work as your ajax call has some issues you need to make your ajax call correct then this way it should work

Comment: Here are my code : http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/BgdnF/3/ , and as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. http://api.jquery.com/live/